# Custom Task/Plugin in gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a custom Task/Plugin (both refuse to work) to use in my gradle build script.

I'm using the groovy plugin and want to declare the Tasks/Plugins in a separate files and not inside my build.gradle.

My project tree is the following:

```
/project
.
|-gradle
|-src
|---main
|-----groovy
|-----java
|-----resources
|---test
|-----groovy
|-----java
|-----resources
|-build.gradle
```

What I tried to do, is create my Task/Plugin classes inside `src/main/groovy` and then use them in my `build.gradle`.

Let me give a small example.

`src/main/groovy/mypackage/`**TestTask.groovy:**

```
package org.gradle.mypackage

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

public class TestTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    def doAction() {

    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile(
        localGroovy(),
        gradleApi()
    )

    testCompile(
        [ group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11' ]
    )

}

task testTask(type: TestTask)
```

When I try to do anything using my gradle.build (clean, build, etc), I get the following error:

> Error:(116, 0) Could not find property 'TestTask' on root project 'project'.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to `import` the Task in `build.gradle` using `import mypackage.TestTask` but that didn't work either.

It looks to me like the groovy files do not compile at all while from what I read in the [docs](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html) gradle should take care of compiling and adding them in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how it works. If you need to provide custom plugins and tasks organized in packages , put the whole code under `buildSrc` directory. Under `$GRADLE_HOME/samples/multiProjectBuildSrc` You can find excellent example how it should be done.

`$GRADLE_HOME` - gradle installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: "in-stackoverflow" solution.

In your project create folder buildSrc/src/main

Don't forget to create build.gradle in buildSrc/

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}
```

Now in the main folder create package with your task, for example: `pl.myAwesomeCompany.gradle.tasks`

```
package pl.myAwesomeCompany.gradle.tasks

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
import org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs

class ExampleTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    void execute(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
        println inputs.incremental ? "CHANGED inputs considered out of date"
            : "ALL inputs considered out of date"
    }
}
```

Voila! Now in your project you can use your plugin:

```
import package pl.myAwesomeCompany.gradle.tasks.ExampleTask
task incremental(type:ExampleTask)
```